# How to access two arrays as associative array in JavaScript with low overhead?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, properties, typescript2.0

When returning a table via Ajax, it can be done with column names and row values separately, like this:

```
let columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
let rows = [
      ["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2", "row 1 col 3"]
    , ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2", "row 2 col 3"]
    , ["row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2", "row 3 col 3"]
    , ["row 4 col 1", "row 4 col 2", "row 4 col 3"]
    , ["row 5 col 1", "row 5 col 2", "row 5 col 3"]
];
```

Or as an associative array like this

```
let rows = [
      { "col1": "row 1 col 1", "col2": "row 1 col 2", "col3": "row 1 col 3" }
    , { "col1": "row 2 col 1", "col2": "row 2 col 2", "col3": "row 2 col 3" }
    , { "col1": "row 3 col 1", "col2": "row 3 col 2", "col3": "row 3 col 3" }
    , { "col1": "row 4 col 1", "col2": "row 4 col 2", "col3": "row 4 col 3" }
    , { "col1": "row 5 col 1", "col2": "row 5 col 2", "col3": "row 5 col 3" }
];
```

Now, if there is much data, the first variant will result in less data to transmit.

The problem is, I can't access it like rows[i]["col1] then, as I can with the second variant.

Now, I could just take the rows and the columns, and create an associative array from that, like

```
let columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];

let data = [
      ["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2", "row 1 col 3"]
    , ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2", "row 2 col 3"]
    , ["row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2", "row 3 col 3"]
    , ["row 4 col 1", "row 4 col 2", "row 4 col 3"]
    , ["row 5 col 1", "row 5 col 2", "row 5 col 3"]
];



let arr = [];


for (let j = 0; j < data.length; ++j)
{
    let obj = {}; // "associative array" or Object

    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i)
    {
        obj[columns[i]] = data[j][i];
    }
    arr.push(obj);
}
```

But then I have to copy the object, which might take time & memory if the rowCount and the columnCount is large.

Is there any good (non-time & non-memory consuming) way to achive this in JavaScript ?

What I would need is indexed properties, but it seems like they don't exist in JavaScript...

The closest I have come is with the proxy object:

```
let columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
let rows = [
      ["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2", "row 1 col 3"]
    , ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2", "row 2 col 3"]
    , ["row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2", "row 3 col 3"]
    , ["row 4 col 1", "row 4 col 2", "row 4 col 3"]
    , ["row 5 col 1", "row 5 col 2", "row 5 col 3"]
];

let cols = {}; // "associative array" or Object

for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i)
{
    cols[columns[i]] = i;
}


let handler2 = {
    get: function (obj, prop, receiver)
    {
        return obj[cols[prop]];
    }
};

// https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-proxies/
let handler = {
    get: function (obj, prop, receiver)
    {
        console.log("obj:", obj, "prop:", prop, "receiver :", receiver);
        //return obj[prop];
        //return obj[cols[prop]];
        return new Proxy(obj[prop], handler2);
    }

    , set: function (obj, key, value)
    {
        console.log(obj, key, value);
    }

};

let p = new Proxy(rows, handler);
```

The problem here is - apart from that IE11 doesn't support proxy - that I need to create a new proxy on each row access, because it looks like proxy doesn't properly support arrays of objects...

Is there any sane way of solving this particular problem in JavaScript in a **good/performant** way ?

About the last thing I want is write code like this:

```
let columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
let rows = [
      ["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2", "row 1 col 3"]
    , ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2", "row 2 col 3"]
    , ["row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2", "row 3 col 3"]
    , ["row 4 col 1", "row 4 col 2", "row 4 col 3"]
    , ["row 5 col 1", "row 5 col 2", "row 5 col 3"]
];

let cols = {}; // "associative array" or Object

for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i)
{
    cols[columns[i]] = i;
}

let index_col1 = cols["col1"];
let index_col2 = cols["col2"];
let index_col3 = cols["col3"];


for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)
{
    console.log("col1:", rows[i][index_col1], "col2:", rows[i][index_col2], "col3:", rows[i][index_col3]);
}
```

which is what I currently have to do...

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays, these things are objects. (If you call them associative arrays, you also have to call *every* other object associative array.)

Comment: `The problem is, I can't access it like rows[i]["col1]` Why not just access by index, rather than index + string? Index alone would seem to be sufficiently intuitive..?

Comment: @idmean: Which is correct, since every JavaScript object is an associative array. But think JS-object whenever you read associtative array, if it disturbs you.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Because if a column is added on the left side, all indices change. You at least have to put every column-index into a variable.

Comment: @idmean: If you gzip, it's also slower. Plus if you add 10 million rows instead of 5, there will probably be a size difference. Also, here you're getting an unrealistic gzip-optimization because every text in each column only differs by one number, which won't be the case in a real-world application. Plus if much of the data is numbers, compression won't help you much.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a function?

Comment: If you are worried about the performance, I suggest you to transform your data each time you receive a chunk. The bottleneck will be on the IO, not on your code.

Comment: @Jorjon: If I were to use a function, i'd need to pass columnName as a string-argument to the rows function. This wouldn't be type-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, got the answer myself. 
It is kindof-possible, by creating a class and sharing the current row index between two proxys:

```
interface IProxyHandler
{
    get(obj, prop, receiver);
}


declare class Proxy
{
    public constructor(obj, handler_callback: IProxyHandler);
}

interface SomeTable
{
    col1: string;
    col2: number;
    col3: Date;
}

export class table<T>
{

    public obj: T[];
    //public columns: map<string, number>;
    public columns: { [key: string]: number };

    protected i: number;
    protected accessor: Proxy;


    //get bar(): boolean
    //{
    //    return null; // this._bar;
    //}
    //set bar(theBar: boolean)
    //{
    //    //this._bar = theBar;
    //}

    public row(index:number): T
    {
        this.i = index;
        return <T><any>this.accessor;
    }

    public rows :T[];

    constructor(rows: any[][], columnNames:string[])
    {
        this.obj = <any>rows;
        this.i = 0;

        // this.columns = columnNames;
        this.columns = {}; // "associative array" or Object

        for (let i = 0; i < columnNames.length; ++i)
        {
            this.columns[columnNames[i]] = i;
        }


        let handler: IProxyHandler = {
            get: function (obj, prop, receiver)
            {
                return this.obj[this.i][this.columns[prop]];
            }
        };

        handler.get = handler.get.bind(this);
        this.row = this.row.bind(this);
        this.accessor = new Proxy(this.obj, handler);

        let handler2: IProxyHandler = {
            get: function (obj, prop, receiver)
            {
                return this.row(prop);
            }
        };
        handler2.get = handler2.get.bind(this);

        this.rows = <any> new Proxy(this.obj, handler2);
    }


}


// https://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy
// Sorry, your browser is no longer supported. 
// If you want this program to support IE11, develop a proxy-polyfill for IE11. 
// Hint from Babel-docs: ES2015-Proxies requires support on the engine level; 
// it is thus not possible to polyfill Proxy in ES5.
export function testTable()
{
    let columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
    let rows = [
        ["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2", "row 1 col 3"]
        , ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2", "row 2 col 3"]
        , ["row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2", "row 3 col 3"]
        , ["row 4 col 1", "row 4 col 2", "row 4 col 3"]
        , ["row 5 col 1", "row 5 col 2", "row 5 col 3"]
    ];

    let x = new table<SomeTable>(rows, columns);

    console.log(x.rows[0].col1);
    // console.log(x.row(1).col1);
    // console.log(x.obj[0][0]);
}
```

**PS:**
If I were to use a function, I'd need to do this:

```
public rowz(index: number, colName: string): any
{
    this.i = index;
    return this.obj[index][this.columns[colName]];
}
```

or this

```
public rowz(index: number): any
{
    this.i = index;

    return function (colName)
    {
        this.obj[index][this.columns[colName]];
    };

}
```

This has the disadvanages that I would lose compile-time type-safety, both with the columnName as well as with the return type. Or I would need to copy the entiry row into an object, which duplicates data/memory-consumption.

---

Another option, which is compatible with ES5/IE11, is using object-properties:

```
interface ITestTable1
{
    col1:number;
    col2:number;
}


interface ITestTable2
{
    a:number;
    b:number;
    c:number;
}



export class TableWrapper<T>
{
    public rows:any[][];
    protected m_accessor:object;
    protected m_i:number;

    protected m_columnMap: { [columnName: string]: number; };
    protected m_columns: string[];
    protected m_columnLength:number;


    public get rowCount(): number
    {
        return this.rows.length;
    }


    public get columnCount(): number
    {
        return this.m_columns.length;
    }


    get columns(): string[]
    {
        return this.m_columns;
    }


    protected setColumns(cols: string[])
    {
        this.m_columnLength = cols.length;

        this.m_columnMap = null;
        this.m_columnMap = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < this.m_columnLength; ++i)
        {
            this.m_columnMap[cols[i]] = i;
        }

        this.m_columns = cols;
    } // End Sub setColumns 


    public row(i:number):T
    {
        this.m_i = i;
        return <T><any>this.m_accessor;
    }


    public getIndex(name:string):number
    {
        return this.m_columnMap[name];
    }


    public addRow(dat:any[])
    {
        this.rows.push(dat);
        return this;
    }


    public removeRow(i:number)
    {
        this.rows.splice(i, 1);
        return this;
    }


    constructor(columns: string[], data: Array<any[]>, ignoreCase?:boolean)
    {
        if (ignoreCase == null)
            ignoreCase = true;

        for (let i = 0; i< columns.length; ++i)
        {
            columns[i] = columns[i].toLowerCase();
        } // Next i 


        let that = this;
        this.getIndex.bind(this);
        this.setColumns.bind(this);
        this.row.bind(this);
        this.addRow.bind(this);
        this.removeRow.bind(this);

        this.rows = data;
        this.setColumns(columns);
        this.m_accessor = { }; // Creates a new object


        for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i)
        {
            let propName = columns[i];

            Object.defineProperty(this.m_accessor, propName, {
                // Using shorthand method names (ES2015 feature). 
                // get() { return bValue;}, 
                // set(value) { bValue = value;}, 
                // This is equivalent to: 
                // get: function() { return bValue; }, 
                // set: function(value) { bValue = value; }, 
                // And could be written as (getter = getter.bind(this)) 
                // get: getter, 
                // set: setter, 
                get: function ()
                { 
                    let currentRow =  <any> that.rows[that.m_i];
                    return currentRow == null ? currentRow : currentRow[i]; 
                },
                set: function(value:any) 
                { 
                    let currentRow =  <any> that.rows[that.m_i];
                    if (currentRow!= null )
                        currentRow[i] = value; 
                },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        } // Next i 

    }

}


let tab: TableWrapper<ITestTable1> = new TableWrapper<ITestTable1>(["col1","col2"], [[1,2], [3,4]]);
// tab.columns=["col1","col2", "col3"];

let hi :TableWrapper<ITestTable2>= new TableWrapper<ITestTable2>(["a","b","c"], [[1,2,3],[4,5,6] ]);


console.log(tab.row(0).col1);
console.log(hi.row(0).a);
console.log(hi.row(1).b);
console.log(hi.row(0).c);

hi.row(0).a = 123;


for (let i = 0; i< hi.rowCount; ++i)
{
    for (let j=0; j < hi.columnCount; ++j)
    {
        console.log(hi.rows[i][j]);

        console.log(hi.row(i).a);
        console.log(hi.row(i).b);
        console.log(hi.row(i).c);

        console.log((<any>hi.row(i))[hi.columns[j]]);
        console.log((<any>hi.row(i))[hi.columns[j]]);
        console.log((<any>hi.row(i))[hi.columns[j]]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I just suggest two different approaches. It entirely depends on how you actually need to access the data later on.

If you need it "row-per-row" your first approach is not that bad. I just would combine both of them into a single result. Does not make sense to have the column definition in a separate array I guess.

```
let rows = [
      ["col1", "col2", "col3"],
      ["row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2", "row 1 col 3"],
      ["row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2", "row 2 col 3"],
      ["row 3 col 1", "row 3 col 2", "row 3 col 3"],
      ["row 4 col 1", "row 4 col 2", "row 4 col 3"],
      ["row 5 col 1", "row 5 col 2", "row 5 col 3"]
];
```

In this approach you have all entries of a row grouped together, and even empty cells are easily treated with null / unedfined values.

If you rather want to access the data "column-per-column" I suggest using an object with the column header as key.

```
let table = {
    "col1": ["row 1 col 1", "row 2 col 1", ..."],
    "col2": ["row 1 col 2", "row 2 col 2", ..."]
}
```

In this approach it is also easily possible (and fast) to get data for a row entry. table['col1'][index]

Comment: But this way you can't just sequentially output the JSON from the db, you've got to read all data into memory first, which is bad and slow.

Comment: actually with both versions it is easily possible to do this. and if you worry about you can't read it to memory from your db, then having everything in one object in your javascript is a pretty bad idea. since your server has (or at least should have) more memory available than most browsers are willing to provide for your webpage

Comment: Except that the browser has just one concurrent user, and the server has many. If you require a GB per user times 100, you're needlessly requireing too much hardware. And no, if you don't want to have all the data in memory, it's not easily possible to do this.

Comment: I don't quite understand... how does the result of one user affect the others? When one user requests data you should only request data for that one user from your DB. And if you can't handle this in memory, chances are the result might also be to big for the browser.

Comment: It doesn't affect the others, but the memory is filled up at the same time, because there is more than one user in the system at the same time, doing the same thing.

Comment: so? If you have trouble with your memory this does sound like a completely different problem. How does the user receive the data? When everything happens in one ajax request you anyway need to have everything in memory at one point in time, so there is no "sequentially output". If he requests in multiple requests this sounds like you need some sort of pagination. If you transfer data over websocket still both versions can handle this. I don't quite understand your problem with "sequentially output"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173382/discussion-between-nicolas-gehlert-and-stefan-steiger).

Comment: No, you don't need to with HTTP 1.1. You can just output it chunked, the server doesn't need to keep all the data in memory, it only needs to keep the current chunk. Only the client does need to keep all his data in memory.